# scroll ListView inside a LinearLayout which is wrapped in ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-scrollview

I have an activity which should be scrollable, therefore i surrounded it with a ScrollView. I have two listViews in there, which i do not want to be as large as it would be necessary to display all items.

It would be nice if i could set a maxHeight property, so that in case there are only 2 items no empty space would be present, but if there are 50 items i would only want to see like 5 of them at a time. Unfortunately there is no such property, so i decided to just set the height to a fixed number. Any advice how to do that more properly would be much appreciated.

However the main problem is that, when i try to scroll one of the listViews the whole LinearLayout scrolls down. (I can avoid this if i use another finger to 'hold' the LinearLayout in place while scrolling the list, but that certainly not a solution.)

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_settings"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="app.ballmaschine.pages.SettingsPage">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Some other stuff here  -->

    <TextView
        android:text="Eine Maschine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lvCalibsM1"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Zwei Maschinen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/lvCalibsM2"/>

    <!-- Some more stuff here  -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you research any solutions before posting? https://www.google.com/search?q=android+listview+in+scrollview

Comment: I did, however most solutions suggest a non-scrollable List-View, which is something i dont want, some say that i schould say the height of the ListView to wrap_content wich i dont want as well. Adding this on tauch listener to ListView solved the scrolling problem: `public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                return false;
            }`

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the ListView

```
android:scrollbars = "none"
```

and this in Java Code

```
listView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

In these cases always try NestedScrollView and also add this line to it

```
 app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```